# which Settings plugin to use in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

The Settings plugin on NuGet

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugins.Settings/0.0.0.2

seems to be only available for Windows Phone.

The name (MvvmCross.Plugins.Settings) makes it look like an 'official' plugin but it's not.

Confusingly, there is also another one for Windows Phone too:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugins.Settings.WindowsPhone/0.0.0.2

both have as author ShawnMclean.

There is also this one, but it's only saving basic types (int, string, double, etc) it is not able to save custom objects:

https://github.com/ceton/Mvx.Plugins.Settings

A very simple implementation would be to serialize a value to JSON. The value can be anything.

What are you using to save settings in your MvvmCross apps?

Answer (score 3):

Cheesebaron has a MvvmCross Settings plugin for Droid, Touch and Windows Phone, based on ceton's plugin, with some fixes:

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins

This plugin also only saves basic types. If you want to save serializable types it shouuld be possible to clone the repo and extend the plugin implementations per platform.

Of course, you can always let your application handle the JSON serialization, and store it as strings, maybe make a nice service for this you can use across your application. After all, JSON serialization should be pretty cross-platform.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of Cheesebaron's implementation. Like you mentioned already, it only saves basic types unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on complexity of your settings, you can consider using http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File/ and just serialize your settings object into XML or JSON.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this. You should be using the native settings capabilities of your platform - otherwise your settings become an invisible silo which cannot be managed by software infrastructure tools. For example, if any of your customers are using MDM infrastructure, they will not be able to push out updated settings to your app.